# How to correctly migrate custom UserModel in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have custom user model from AbstractUser. And in the user model i have 1 field as foreignKey to other model. So i can't make migrations because i recieve error:

```
no such table: app_userrate
```

I tired to comment this foreignKey field but it is not soulution cause i want to auto deploy app.

```py
class UserRate(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False)
    max_active_events_cnt = models.PositiveIntegerField(default = 5)
    max_people_contacts_cnt = models.PositiveIntegerField(default = 30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

def default_rate():
    obj, created = UserRate.objects.get_or_create(name="Basic")
    return obj.id

class User(AbstractUser):
    rate = models.ForeignKey(UserRate, on_delete=models.PROTECT, default=default_rate)
    rate_until = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I want to understand what should i change to make migrations correctly

Answer (score 3):

This isn't really about the user model specifically, nor about foreign keys. It's about the default attribute, which you have set to call a function which itself does a database lookup. Obviously, at the time the migrations are run, the db item does not exist.

There is a solution, but it will take a few steps. You would need to remove the default attribute at first and create the migrations without it (you may need to set null=True). Then, add a second migration to define the "Basic" UserRate object. Finally, add the default back in and create a third migration.

Comment: Thank you. But i want to find soulution with one migration. Cause i want to do CI/CD and there are no such possibilities.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. CI will run all the migrations in one go, you just need to *create* the migrations separately.